# Is there a way to target Windows Mail 10 and 11 without affecting Outlook desktop?

Tags: css, email, html-email, email-client, darkmode

I have this code hack that will keep white text on a black background in most dark mode clients except Windows mail 10 and 11.

The <!--[if mso 16]> conditional statement works for Outlook (OL 365, OL 2021) desktop but doesn't display properly for Windows Mail 10 and 11. Windows Mail likes the css used in the <!--[if !mso 16]> conditional statement block. Is there mso conditional code that will specifically target only Windows Mail 10 and 11?

Is there another way to go about applying the styles to separate Outlook (OL Office 365 Dark, Outlook 2021 Dark) and Windows Mail?

```
 <!--[if gte mso 16]>   
    <style>   
    .keep-white { mso-style-textfill-type:gradient; mso-style-textfill-fill-gradientfill-stoplist:"0 #FFFFFF 0 100000\,100000 #FFFFFF 0 100000"; color:#000000 !important; }   
     </style>  
     <![endif]-->
<style>   
u + .body .gmail-screen { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:screen; }
u + .body .gmail-difference { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:difference; }
</style>
```

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:640px;background-color:#000000;" role="presentation">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<![endif]-->

    <table role="presentation" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;Margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" align="center">
      <tr>
       <td class="body" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%, #000000 100%);max-width:640px;" width="100%" valign="top" align="center">
                 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                 <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:640px;" fillcolor="#000000">
                 <v:fill type="gradient" color2="#000000"/>
                 <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                 <center>
                 <![endif]-->
        <table role="presentation" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;Margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
             <tr>
              <td style="padding:40px 10px 40px;" align="center">
         <p style="padding:0;margin:0;font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:34px;color:#ffffff;text-align:center;" class="txt16">
  <!--[if mso 16]><strong style="color:#ffffff;" class="keep-white"><![endif]-->      
  <!--[if !mso 16]><!-- --><strong style="font-weight:400;color:#ffffff;" class="gmail-screen"><span class="gmail-difference"><!--<![endif]--> 

Combo text hack. Works everywhere except Windows 10 &amp; 11 mail.

<!--[if mso 16]></strong><![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso 16]><!-- --></span></strong><!--<![endif]-->
        </p>
            </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
                 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                 </center>
                 </v:textbox>
                 </v:rect>
                 <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
```

I applied the <!--[if mso 16]> conditional statement that targets both outlook and windows mail 10 and 11, but found that windows mail dark mode treats css differently than outlook dark mode does.

Answer (score 0):

**Dark mode for Outlook**

Dark Mode Meta Tags

```
<!--Dark Mode meta tags needed to enable Dark Mode in email client user agents-->
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark only">
<style type="text/css">
  :root {
    color-scheme: light dark;
    supported-color-schemes: light dark;
  }
</style>
```

Target Android/Outlook.com for Dark Mode

```
  <!--Dark Mode media queries to target some Android and Outlook.com -->
  <style>
    /* targets color attribute */
    [data-ogsc] .fubar { }

    /* targets background attribute */
    [data-ogsb] .fubar { }
  </style>
```

There is a lot of more info for dark mode that can be found here:

https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/

You can use either of the two methods below to target Windows Mail:

```
/* Windows Mail (Phone & Surface) */
_:-ms-input-placeholder, :root .your-class-name {
  /* Replace this comment with your styles */
}
```

or

```
/* Windows Mail (Phone & Surface) */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .your-class-name {
  /* Replace this comment with your styles */
}
```

Both of these were submitted to https://howtotarget.email/ by Mark Robbins.

Comment: Thanks @Syfer. That is a very handy link but I need to send different css to windows mail 10 and 11 desktop for dark mode. Any idea how to specify different css to Windows mail 10 desktop than the css specified for Outlook 2021 desktop?

Comment: @AmericanGirl I have updated my answer with more info. Hope that helps